# Solving the Poisson equation in 3D using Python

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, poissons-equation

I'm implementing a Python code where I need to solve the following Poisson equation as one of the steps:

$$\nabla^2p=f(\mathbf r)$$

I am using a 3D rectangular grid with ~100 points on each direction. The finite difference equation I get is

$$p_{i, j, k}=\frac{k^2l^2(p_{i+1, j, k}+p_{i-1, j, k})+h^2l^2(p_{i, j+1, k}+p_{i, j-1, k})+h^2k^2(p_{i, j, k+1}+p_{i, j, k-1})+h^2k^2l^2 f_{i, j, k}}{2(h^2+k^2+l^2)}$$

where $h, k, l$ are the mesh spacings in the $x, y, z$ directions, respectively. This can obviously be expressed as a matrix equation and in principle I could just invert the matrix acting on the $p$s. However it would be a ~$10^6\times10^6$ matrix, which would require me to have  ~$10^{13}$ bits (assuming I use 16 bit floating point numbers) of memory, which comes to about 1TB at the very least, which is ~80 times more than what I have installed in my computer. There must be a better way to solve this, but I'm not proficient in numerical methods for PDEs.

I saw [this article](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/IPAC2014/doi/JACoW-IPAC2014-MOPME013.html) by Profs. Pöplau and Portratz that deals with a generalized version of the code I'm trying to implement (they use a variable mesh spacing near the boundaries to simulate arbitrary shaped boundaries). However, the code that is presented in the article is incomplete, and I've been unable to reverse-engineer it to use it myself. I tried sending an email to Prof. Pöplau, who is the correspondence author, but the address no longer exists.

Could you point me towards literature about methods similar to Pöplau and Portratz's that I can use for my code? Or is there another already implemented library/package/code I could adapt or use to solve the Poisson equation numerically?

Note: The boundary conditions I'm using could be expressed as either Dirichlet or Von Neumann. However, periodic boundary conditions would not work, because the function I'm interested in is not necessarily periodic.

Comment: Relaxation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(iterative_method)) is a fine method for this equation. It is very easy to implement, though to get fast convergence one typically needs multigrid.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm

Comment: Please take a look at this great book on iterative methods for sparse systems https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf

Comment: FFT-based methods will be quite fast for your problem (rectangular domain, regular grid, Diriclet or Neumann conditions), but they are a bit tricky to implement correctly

Comment: I thought FFT methods were better suited to periodic boundary conditions. I'll certainly look at that book to get a better idea on them. Thank you.

Comment: @Chaotic For Dirichlet boundary conditions discrete sine transform (of type 1) is used, and for Neumann - discrete cosine transform (of type 1 too, iirc). Both DCT and DST are very similar to FFT and usually are implemented in same software packages

Answer (score 1):

***Too long for a comment.***

1. It is a bad idea to denote one index and one mesh spacing, both, by $\color{red}{k}$. Better use $h_i,h_j,h_k$ for the mesh spacings.
2. From

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}&\approx\frac{p_{i+1,j,k}-p_{i,j,k}}{h_i}\\[3mm]
\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}&\approx\frac{p_{i+1,j,k}-2p_{i,j,k}+p_{i-1,j,k}}{h_i^2}\\
\end{align}
I get
\begin{align}
\nabla^2p&\approx\frac{p_{i+1,j,k}-2p_{i,j,k}+p_{i-1,j,k}}{h_i^2}\\
&+\frac{p_{i,j+1,k}-2p_{i,j,k}+p_{i,j-1,k}}{h_j^2}\\
&+\frac{p_{i,j,k+1}-2p_{i,j,k}+p_{i,j,k-1}}{h_k^2}\,.
\end{align}
What has this to do with your expression ?

3. When I imagine a cube with $100$ cells in each direction I see a total number of $10^6$ grid points, not a $10^6\times 10^6$ matrix.

Comment: 1) You' re right, it's confusing to use the same letter to denote two different things, sorry for that oversight (I originally had the spacings as $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z$, but the equation was too long and the fraction's numerator had 2 lines, hence the change, albeit careless). 2) I express the Laplacian in the same way, to get my equation I solve for $p_{i, j, k}$ with $f$ in the RHS. 3) What I mean is that the finite difference equation can be expressed as a matrix equation where the variables are the $p$s, in that sense there would be $10^6$ variables with a linear (matrix) equation